# What is wrong with 20newsgroup-18828 dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

i am currently using 20NewsGroup-18828 dataset in weka. I have selected a subset of document with 100 per category (total 2000 documents) which i divided in a split of 70%(training) and 30%(testing) when i tried classification with naive bayes, SVM and K-nn its accuracy is very low.Here are list of operations i am performing on the dataset

1. StringtoWordVector (indexing and term weighting with Tf-Idf, Smart stopword list, Snowball stemmer)
2. Dimensionality reduction with feature selection (InformationGain)
3. Dimensionality reduction with feature transformation (Random Projection)

When i use original dataset with 20,000 docs it performs well but it has duplications like some documents are classified in multiple categories.

Did any one used this dataset or can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regarding differences between datasets

The main difference between 20newsgroup ( **o** riginal dataset) and 20newsgroup-18828 (**m** odified) is:

- o contains duplicates, m does not
- o contains **trivial** problem, as it includes **newsgroup identification header**, m includes only **from** and **subject** headers (so it is still easy version of the problem, but harder than o), for example:

**FILE 51126 regarding atheism**

in original form:

> Path:
>   cantaloupe.srv.cs.cmu.edu!crabapple.srv.cs.cmu.edu!fs7.ece.cmu.edu!europa.eng.gtefsd.com!howland.reston.ans.net!noc.near.net!news.centerline.com!uunet!olivea!sgigate!sgiblab!adagio.panasonic.com!nntp-server.caltech.edu!keith
>   From: keith@cco.caltech.edu (Keith Allan Schneider) Newsgroups:
>   **alt.atheism** Subject: Re: >>>>>>Pompous ass Message-ID:
>   <1pi9btINNqa5@gap.caltech.edu> Date: 2 Apr 93 20:57:33 GMT References:
>   <1ou4koINNe67@gap.caltech.edu> <1p72bkINNjt7@gap.caltech.edu>
>   <93089.050046MVS104@psuvm.psu.edu> <1pa6ntINNs5d@gap.caltech.edu>
>   <1993Mar30.210423.1302@bmerh85.bnr.ca> <1pcnqjINNpon@gap.caltech.edu>
>    Organization: California Institute
>   of Technology, Pasadena Lines: 9 NNTP-Posting-Host:
>   punisher.caltech.edu
>
> kmr4@po.CWRU.edu (Keith M. Ryan) writes:
>
> >>Then why do people keep asking the same questions over and over?
>
> >Because you rarely ever answer them.
>
> Nope, I've answered each question posed, and most were answered
>   multiple times.
>
> keith

In modified form (-18828 version)

> From: keith@cco.caltech.edu (Keith Allan Schneider)
>
> Subject: Re: >>>>>>Pompous ass
>
> kmr4@po.CWRU.edu (Keith M. Ryan) writes:
>
> >>Then why do people keep asking the same questions over and over?
>
> >Because you rarely ever answer them.
>
> Nope, I've answered each question posed, and most were answered
>   multiple times.
>
> keith

As you can see, original data is so simple, that you actually can find the name of the label inside of the file... this is why you will always get good scores on such data, even if your whole processing concept is very, very wrong.

So the question is not "what is wrong with 20newsgroup-18828" but rather "what is wrong with the original dataset".

## General ideas

First, why would you assume that anything is wrong? You are performing very arbitrary methods of data representation processing (two different dimensionality reduction steps) on the very small (70 training vectors per class) dataset. There is nothing wrong with this data, this is a simple NLP data, which, as most of the NLP tasks **require** large amounts of data, and "naive" (not NLP-based) dimensionality reduction techniques have no guarantees to actually help.

Secod, even if you do something wrong, in 90% os cases (arbitrary high number) **the error is between what user think he does, and what he actually does**. So describing what you do won't lead to any help, you have to **show** what you exactly do (by giving a reproducible example).

Comment: thanx for answering,  Yes but as i mentioned that as i applied the same Naive Bayes on same training/test(70 training, 30 testing) split from original 20,000 documents dataset. The accuracy it produced was 89%. This made me think that their may be some problem with the dataset. The problem with original dataset(20, 000) was that it contains many documents which were duplicated in more than one category where i was trying to do multi-class classification where each document needs to belong from exactly one category.

Comment: I missed this problem, you can find the updates answer with details of what is happening.

Comment: thanx alot for update, it helped alot. Yes i also observed the differences in those files. Just a thought if i add headers to 20NG-18828(m) from original dataset(o) i may achieve both things like duplication is achieved and classifier score are improved ?? secondly i am dealing with supervised learning don't you think that data set with header will make it easier for classifier to predict test document ?

Comment: It makes it **trivial** to predict, this is why I stated that the original data is **trivial**. Even the alternated version is still easy, as you have "author" field, and your clasifier actually will learn names of users active in the particular newsgroup. True test can be performed with **ll** headers removed. Such data can be obtained in scikit-learn library with specific header removal options.